# EJS tags in javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ejs

I'm using Node.js and ejs for templating language.

I feel like this is really silly and I should be able to solve it, but I'm stuck.

I am having trouble with the following function:

```
// Returns true if campground has been posted by currently logged on user
// If no user logged on, returns false
function checkIfCampgroundBelongsToUser(campgroundAuthorID) {
    var currentUser = <%-JSON.stringify(currentUser) %>
    if(currentUser && currentUser._id === campgroundAuthorID) { 
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This code works fine when a user is logged in. However, when no user is logged in evaluates to empty. Not empty string. Not null. Not undefined. Just empty. Thus, I get the following error

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if

When I inspect via chrome dev tools, this is what I see

[image]

(yes I realize a semi-colon is missing, I added it... And when I do, I get uncaught syntaxError: Unexpected token ;)

Comment: You could try -> `<%-currentUser ? JSON.stringify(currentUser) : "null" %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`undefined` will pass through `JSON.stringify` unchanged and EJS will render that as nothing. If you default it to `null` it'll be converted to the string `"null"`, which EJS will render as `null`.

```
var currentUser = <%- JSON.stringify(currentUser || null) %>;
```